# Draw a Text in 3D

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, text-rendering

I'm trying to figure out how to draw text in 3D.

Right now I have two ways to display stuff onto the screen. One that uses usual 3d space to render the world, and additional render to render the HUD that does it in pretransformed way.

So, ideally I would like a way to do the same for text, to both render a string in 3D (kind of like "billboarding" way) and pretransformed way (as if I was using 2d mode).

The only thing that I was able to find is to use "Mesh.FromText", but it doesn't seem to be what I need. Oh, and also using spritebatch to draw text to a texture, and then using this texture in 3D with alpha blending, but again it seems like a crappy way to do it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw with `SpriteBatch` in 3D space by using a custom effect. [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) has the details.

It's as simple as passing an effect (like `BasicEffect`) with the correct transformations set on it to the appropriate overload of `SpriteBatch.Begin` ([this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433700.aspx)).

(The text is made up of transparent sprites - so all the usual caveats with drawing with transparency in 3D apply: sort and draw over the opaque, Z-buffered scene, or use alpha-testing.)

Comment: Sorry, it's beyond my understanding :(

Comment: What, specifically are you having trouble with? (If it's a big thing, perhaps ask a fresh question?)

Comment: Well, pretty much everything unfortunately, decause there is no example code of actual technik you described... :(

Comment: Do you know how to use `BasicEffect` to draw things in 3D? If not, you'll need to go and learn how. The basic idea is to set appropriate world/view/projection matrices so that your 3D points end up in the right place on the 2D screen... Then look at the last block of code in the [blog post I linked](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) - note how it sets the world/view/projection matrices for 2D drawing. All you have to do is set the appropriate matrices for **3D** drawing instead. Then use `SpriteBatch` as per normal.

Comment: Okay, I think I got the idea, tho as you said I need to learn how to do some of that stuff first. But thank you for explanation :)